# How do I parse, flatten, and convert a large JSON file into a CSV file?

Tags: c#, python, .net, json, csv

Essentially I have a large (~1 GB) file in which each line is a JSON object, containing nested properties, some of whose values may be arrays of objects.

Example of an object:

```
{
  "business_id": "b9WZJp5L1RZr4F1nxclOoQ",
  "full_address": "1073 Washington Ave\nCarnegie, PA 15106",
  "hours": {
    "Monday": {
      "close": "14:30",
      "open": "06:00"
    },
    "Tuesday": {
      "close": "14:30",
      "open": "06:00"
    },
    "Friday": {
      "close": "14:30",
      "open": "06:00"
    },
    "Wednesday": {
      "close": "14:30",
      "open": "06:00"
    },
    "Thursday": {
      "close": "14:30",
      "open": "06:00"
    },
    "Sunday": {
      "close": "12:30",
      "open": "07:00"
    },
    "Saturday": {
      "close": "12:30",
      "open": "06:00"
    }
  },
  "open": true,
  "categories": ["Breakfast & Brunch", "Restaurants"],
  "city": "Carnegie",
  "review_count": 38,
  "name": "Gab & Eat",
  "neighborhoods": [],
  "longitude": -80.084799799999999,
  "state": "PA",
  "stars": 4.5,
  "latitude": 40.396744099999999,
  "attributes": {
    "Alcohol": "none",
    "Noise Level": "average",
    "Has TV": true,
    "Attire": "casual",
    "Ambience": {
      "romantic": false,
      "intimate": false,
      "classy": false,
      "hipster": false,
      "divey": true,
      "touristy": false,
      "trendy": false,
      "upscale": false,
      "casual": true
    },
    "Good for Kids": true,
    "Wheelchair Accessible": false,
    "Delivery": false,
    "Caters": true,
    "BYOB": false,
    "Corkage": false,
    "Accepts Credit Cards": false,
    "BYOB/Corkage": "yes_free",
    "Take-out": true,
    "Price Range": 1,
    "Outdoor Seating": false,
    "Takes Reservations": false,
    "Waiter Service": true,
    "Wi-Fi": "no",
    "Order at Counter": true,
    "Good For": {
      "dessert": false,
      "latenight": false,
      "lunch": false,
      "dinner": false,
      "brunch": false,
      "breakfast": true
    },
    "Parking": {
      "garage": false,
      "street": false,
      "validated": false,
      "lot": true,
      "valet": false
    },
    "Good For Kids": true,
    "Good For Groups": false
  },
  "type": "business"
},
```

How do I flatten this and convert it into CSV so that I have a single object with properties (columns) like `business_id`, `hours.Monday.close`, `attributes.Ambience.hipster` etc?

The issue is that not all the objects have all the properties, so I need to scan the entire file to get a list of all possible flat properties. Essentially I am trying to mimic the functionality of [json2csv](http://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm), except that for array-valued properties, I don't split it into multiple columns, but store the entire array string as a value in CSV.

How do I accomplish this using Python or .NET?

Answer (score 1):

This works. Might need to expand upon it a bit more to drill through arrays, etc. Uses Newtonsoft's JSON library, and assumes the JSON string is an *object*, not an array or a primitive (or anything else)

```
void Main()
{
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStr) as JObject;    
    var props = GetPropPaths(string.Empty, obj);
    props.Dump();
}

private IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> GetPropPaths(string currPath, JObject obj)
{
    foreach(var prop in obj.Properties())
    {
        var propPath = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currPath) ? prop.Name : currPath + "." + prop.Name;

        if (prop.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {   
            foreach(var subProp in GetPropPaths(propPath, prop.Value as JObject))
                yield return subProp;
        } else {
            yield return new Tuple<string, string>(propPath, prop.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

For your above json, it gives the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort to actually try this out! There's still one issue though. As I said, my file contains a JSON object in each line. So if I do this for each object, I would get a corresponding dictionary. However, the dictionary for each object would not contain keys not present in it, but present in other objects. How do I then get a list of all possible keys for my CSV header?

Comment: @AmateurProgrammer You'd have to do something like.. `var headers = new HashSet<string>(); foreach(var dictionary in dictionaries) { foreach (var header in dictionary.Keys) { headers.Add(header); } }`

Comment: But this means that I would have to store all the dictionaries in memory, which is exactly what I want to avoid, because the file is too large.